# Elvis operator with hyphenated properties in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-template

How to use elvis operator when accessing hyphenated properties in angular2 templates

http://plnkr.co/edit/z3Wqn7EScgxcAhrFJWjv?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
     {{asyncObj1?.theprop}}
     {{asyncObj2?['the-prop']}} <!-- this throws error -->
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {

    setTimeout(function(){
      this.asyncObj1 = {
      'theprop': 'value'
    } 
      this.asyncObj2 = {
      'the-prop': 'async value'
    }  
    }, 2000) 

  }
}
```

Comment: You would need a ngIf. Something like `<div *ngIf="asyncObj2">{{asyncObj2['the-prop']}}</div>`

Comment: or `<template [ngIf]="asyncObj2"> {{asyncObj2['the-prop']}} </template>` , which wouldn't leave any extra markup ie- `div wrapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't seem you currently can, because it doesn't appear to have been added with support for indexer notation.

This was added to Angular 2 in [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/2152/files) pull request, since issue [#16](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16) in Typescript is "blocked" or on hold until there is standardized ES support for such an operator.

Essentially, it is possible that the operator could be expanded within Angular2 to support both . property syntax AND indexer syntax, but the pull request doesn't seem to offer any indication that this was the intention nor that it is currently supported, particularly when you look at the associated tests.